# Java: How to get intercept on Filter after it returns from the controller

Tags: java, servlets

I have implemented a Filter like this but this triggers only when the request is coming in. I would like to intercept the response on its way out i.e. when the response is returned from controller.

I know about Spring Interceptors which give you the functionality to handle the request before and after it hits the controller. I would like to do something like that.

```
public class ServiceSessionManagementInterceptor implements Filter{

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,  FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map<String, String[]> maps = request.getParameterMap();

    System.out.println("test");
chain.doFilter(request, response);  
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Put code after chain.doFilter() that you want executed on the way out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `doFilter()` is where magic happens. Whatever you put before it will be executed before the servlet and everything you put after it will be executed after the servlet `service()` method returns (including a forward/include, etc.).

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,  FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    System.out.println("before");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);  
    System.out.println("after");
}
```

This way you could wrap the `ServletRequest` and `ServletResponse` objects with your own implementations to add functionality, ex: compression.

Note that a Spring `Interceptor` is called before and after the handler method gets executed. A servlet `Filter` gets executed before and after a `Servlet`.

Comment: [FilterChain.doFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/FilterChain.html#doFilter-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-) supports the answer.

Comment: A note , don't try to change anything to the response at that point ( changing Headers, adding cookies, etc) after the doFilter() because the response will most likely be committed already and your action will have no effect

Comment: @sam so what is the alternative approach to modify response after it returns from controller.

Comment: As you might imagine, I have not a single memory of that subject, after 8 years